# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the Controller (?)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

*I've seen a few questions mentioning a similar error but none that require this solution.*

I started writing a Nest app and initially wrote all of my logic in `AppController` and `AppService` and now want to move those to a separate module, `CostsModule` (and associated `CostsController` and `CostsService`).

I ran `nest g module costs`, `nest g service costs`, then `nest g controller costs`, and things work fine until I try to inject `CostsService` into `CostsController`'s constructor. I get the following error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CostsController (?). Please make sure that the argument Function at index [0] is available in the CostsModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If Function is a provider, is it part of the current CostsModule?
- If Function is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CostsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing Function */ ]
  })
```

This sounds odd to me, since what I'm trying to inject *is* a provider, and it *is* part of CostsModule. It also says the argument is a `Function`, which makes me think it might not be referring to that specific injection, though the error goes away if I comment that line out. Code snippets:

```
// src/app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), CostsModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
// src/costs/costs.module.ts

@Module({
  controllers: [CostsController],
  providers: [CostsService],
})
export class CostsModule {}
```

```
// src/costs/costs.controller.ts

// ... other imports omitted for brevity, but this one is problematic.
import type { CostsService } from './costs.service';

@Controller('costs')
export class CostsController {
  // If I comment out the line below, the error goes away.
  constructor(private readonly costsService: CostsService) {}

  @Put('fetch')
  updateCosts(
    @Query(
      'ids',
      new ParseArrayPipe({ items: String, separator: ',' })
    )
    ids: string[]
  ): string {
    return this.costsService.updateCosts(ids);
  }
}
```

```
// src/costs.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class CostsService {
  updateCosts(ids: string[]): string {
    return ids.join(',');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This import was added automatically by VS Code, but the provider (`CostsService`) needs to be imported into the file (not just as a type):

```
import type { CostsService } from './costs.service';
```

Changing the import to the following fixes the issue:

```
import { CostsService } from './costs.service';
```